# Total Found Count Miss-match while doing sorting V2.1 Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

When i do sorting on some unixtimestamp date field the total_found count shows different result . Here is my Query

```
SELECT * FROM CA_SAC_persons,CA_KC_persons,CA_SFC_persons,CA_SJ_persons
WHERE MATCH('@fullname("^John$" | "^Joseph$" | "^Jose$" | "^Josh$" | "^Robs$")') 
ORDER BY filing_date_ts DESC LIMIT 0,1;SHOW META; 

Result :
+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| total         | 1000        |
| total_found   | 4813        |
| time          | 0.019       |
| docs[9]       | 4603        | 
| hits[9]       | 5312        |
+---------------+-------------+

SELECT * FROM CA_SAC_persons,CA_KC_persons,CA_SFC_persons,CA_SJ_persons
WHERE MATCH('@fullname("^John$" | "^Joseph$" | "^Jose$" | "^Josh$" | "^Robs$")') 
ORDER BY filing_date_ts ASC LIMIT 0,1;SHOW META; 

Result :
+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| total         | 1000        |
| total_found   | 4812        |
| time          | 0.019       |
| docs[9]       | 4603        | 
| hits[9]       | 5312        |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Why the total_found shows 1 record less in the 2nd Query ?

Comment: Reported on Sphinx forum http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=12084